# Advice on TIAA-CREF allocation?

Tags: united-states, investing, retirement

I'm in a TIAA-CREF program, which (I think) is like a 401(k).  I say "I think" because I haven't studied 401(k)'s, having never invested in one.

My question: is there anything special about TIAA-CREF that would change one's strategy from the well-known advice for 401(k)'s?

Comment: Is it a 403(b)?  That is a non-profit version of a 401(k)

Answer (score 1):

Usually there is an advisor associated with the plan who can talk to -- I'd advise doing so.

The traditional TIAA-CREF offering was an annuity program to provide defined benefit pensions to professors and other educational workers. Today, they are a financial services company that offers a variety of investments.